# How much kinetic energy would a star in a galaxy have if it fell to the center?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, potential, galaxies

I want to calculate the speed, or equivalently, the kinetic energy of a star, if it had no rotational speed and fell from a given radius to the center of the galaxy.

I assume Newton's shell theorem works as a fair approximation.

Comment: Most big galaxies have a big black hole at the centre, so the answer to your question depends on who is estimating the kinetic energy but becomes arbitrarily large for an observer close to the black hole. I suspect though what you really want to know is how the kinetic energy varies with radius for an infalling object. In which case perhaps rephrase the question.

Comment: Could you add some info? What kind of galaxy, rotating or not? If it is a spirally rotating galaxy, what do you mean "no rotational speed"? In which reference frame?

Answer (score 2):

A fair answer can be achieved using Newtonian physics. Assuming that the star was stationary prior to infall (as you want), we would need to find its potential energy. If it falls to the center, then the gained kinetic energy can be equated to this potential energy.

Let's assume that the star is at $r = R$. To calculate the star's potential energy, we would need to find the amount of mass within the region $r < R$. This mass will come from three sources:

**(i)** The massive black hole at the center say with mass $M_{\rm BH}$

**(ii)** The mass of the disk (I have ignored the bulge), for which we may use a power law density profile like $$\rho = 
\rho_0\left(r / R_{\rm in}\right)^{-n} e^{-z^2 / 2 H^2}
,$$ where $H$ is the disk scale height. This can be integrated over $z$ to give a surface density as $$\Sigma = \rho_0\left(r / R_{\rm in}\right)^{-n} \sqrt{2\pi}H$$ Here, $\rho_0$ is the density in the $z=0$ plane and $R_{\rm in}$ is the inner radius of the disk and can be approximated as $\mathcal{O}(R_s)$, $R_s$ being the Schwarzschild radius of the black hole of mass $M_{\rm BH}$. Though I haven't checked, but you might find the values of some of the other unknown parameters [here](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/465/1/76/2417479).

**(iii)** The mass of the dark matter halo. We can assume an NFW profile here with $$\rho = \frac{\rho_0}{ \frac{r}{r_0} \left(1 + \frac{r}{r_0} \right)^2}$$
and for a Milway-like galaxy you can take $\rho_0 = 0.052 M_{\odot}/pc^3$ and $r_0 = 8.1$ kpc  [[Ref]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.08419.pdf).

Now, we can find the total mass contained within $r<R$ by integrating over $r$ and  $\phi$ for (ii) and (iii) - the $\phi$ integral will just be $2\pi$. From this, we can then directly calculate the potential energy of the star.

Comment: Assuming there is only a disk (no SMBH or halo), how is the potential energy calculated?

Comment: But the potential energy varies with distance to the center when the star is falling.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation curve $v ( r )$ for the galaxy will give the centripetal force experienced at any radial position $F = \frac{mv^2}{r}$. The kinetic energy in this scenario would be $ \frac{mV^2}{2} = KE = \int_0^R F dr$. Here $V$ is the star’s velocity on reaching the galactic centre, $R$ is its initial position and $m$ is its mass.

Comment: I want to find the kinetic energy that a star has in free fall if it did not rotate and had no centripetal acceleration.

Comment: @Manuel the force on a body at a given radius is the same regardless of if that body is in free fall or in orbit. What FTT is saying is that the force on *any* body at $r$ is $mv(r)^2/r$, where $v(r)$ is the speed of orbiting bodies at $r$. You can think of the rotation curve as a sort of proxy for the enclosed mass.